# Как поймать момент скролла в контроле Combo Box Edit в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Как поймать момент скролла в контроле Combo Box Edit в WPF C#
и сделать ленивую подгрузку из запроса, можно на примере?
Данные приходят из API.

Comment: Нужно переопределить `ControlTemplate`, написать свою разметку контрола.

Comment: [Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976907/12888024)